# Fatal error when passing parameter by reference

Tags: php, fatal-error, php-7.0

In our PHP app there is a function to send a mail with `PHPMailer` while collecting the logs of the sending process:

```
function sendWithLog(PHPMailer $mail, &$debug_log, $log_level = PHPMailer_SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION) {
    $debug_log = [];
    $mail->SMTPDebug = $log_level ?: PHPMailer_SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
    $mail->Debugoutput = function($message) use(&$debug_log) {
        $debug_log[] = $message;
    };

    $sent = $mail->send();

    $debug_log = !$sent
                ? $mail->ErrorInfo
                . ($debug_log ? "\n" . implode("\n", $debug_log) : "")
                : "";

    return $sent;
}
```

So, the variable `$debug_log`, passed by reference, should first be initialized as an empty array, and at the end it is made into a string.

If the function is called again, passing as `$debug_log` the `$debug_log` of the previous call, I see this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

However, the variable should still be initialized as empty array before being bound to the closure with the `use()` statement, so I really do not understand how this error can happen.

I tried reproducing the behaviour with a simplified version of the code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f34804f5581f7adbf9de605aae8fcb265d2e24f), but it doesn't seem to trigger the error.

EDIT:

I have solved the problem by changing the function like this:

```
function sendWithLog(PHPMailer $mail, &$debug_log, $log_level = PHPMailer_SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION) {
    $messages = []; // <-- different variable for collecting the log messages!
    $mail->SMTPDebug = $log_level ?: PHPMailer_SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;
    $mail->Debugoutput = function($message) use(&$messages) {
        $messages[] = $message;
    };

    $sent = $mail->send();

    $debug_log = !$sent
                ? $mail->ErrorInfo
                . ($messages ? "\n" . implode("\n", $messages) : "")
                : "";

    return $sent;
}
```

However, I am still wondering how it could trigger the error in the first place.

An example of usage is the following:

```
// $users -> query result from database
while($user = $users->fetch()) {
  // build mail and then
  $sent = sendWithLog($mail, $mail_log);
  // here $mail_log should be initialized to NULL the first time by the PHP engine
  // and in subsequent calls it is the log string of the previous call which should be
  // reset to [] first thing inside the function call

  if(!$sent) {
    error_log("ERROR SENDING MAIL: $mail_log");
  }
}
```

EDIT 2

Here is a sample stack trace:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/AGEws/Mail.php:134
Stack trace:
0 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/PHPMailer/SMTP.php(220): AGEws_Mail::{closure}('CLIENT -> SERVE...', 1)
1 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/PHPMailer/SMTP.php(991): PHPMailer_SMTP->edebug('CLIENT -> SERVE...', 1)
2 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/PHPMailer/SMTP.php(885): PHPMailer_SMTP->client_send('QUIT\r\n')
3 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/PHPMailer/SMTP.php(827): PHPMailer_SMTP->sendCommand('QUIT', 'QUIT', 221)
4 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/PHPMailer.php(1721): PHPMailer_SMTP->quit()
5 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/PHPMailer.php(670): PHPMailer->smtpClose()
6 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/AGEws/Mail.php(147): PHPMailer->__destruct()
7 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/AGEws/Mail.php(118): AGEws_Mail::sendWithLog(NULL, 'SMTP Error: Dat...', 3)
8 /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/AGEws/Cron/Import.php(154): AGEws_Mail::prepareAndSendWithLog('SMTP Error: Dat...', Array, 'Risu in /opt/agews64/www/includes/class/AGEws/Mail.php on line 134
```

Comment: How is $debug_log defined outside of the function, since its being passed as an reference? If its already declared as a string before you start the function, it can't be converted to an array. This will also happen if you run the function twice.

Comment: How you are calling the `sendWithLog` function?

Comment: @OleHaugset the variable is not defined, it is called as `sendWithLog($mail, $mail_log);`, leaving the first initialization to `null` to PHP, subsequent calls use the previous `$mail_log`, which is a string that should immediately be reset to array inside the function

Comment: Make sure you declare `$debug_log = [];` before the function call.

Comment: @MarkusZeller that should not be required (but certainly recommended), since the function itself re-inits the by-ref argument to empty array.

Comment: _I have already solved the problem itself by separating the variables._ What do you mean by this? (I'm also trying to understand)

Comment: @minitauros see the edit.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Are you able to get a stack trace for the error?

Comment: @OleHaugset see the latest edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was *just* too long for a comment, so let me type it here:

The only thing I can think of considering your example - and I'm unsure about the internals at work here, but let me try to explain anyway - is:

You set `$mail->Debugoutput` to be a callable that appends an item to `$debug_log`. Now, when at the end of your function you set `$debug_log` to be a string (`$debug_log = !$sent` etc.), *during* that setting of a string, it might happen that during the `implode()` that happens when the string concatenation happens for some reason the `$mail->Debugoutput` is called again (maybe during a `__toString()`?), which tries to append an array item to `$debug_log`, which is impossible, because it is being set to be a string. Hence the error.

Comment: Looking again at the stack trace, it seems you might be very much right! The closure call is triggered by the mail instance `destruct()`, which is called AFTER the `$debug_log` update has already been changed to string! I really didn't notice that!

Comment: Important lesson learned: do not reuse variables, especially if passed by reference.

Comment: Took me a while to notice but glad we appear to have figured it out! :]